# Why does my Mineraft plugin give me the error "cannot find main class"?

Tags: java, server, minecraft, bukkit

I have just started to learn how to develop Minecraft server plugins but whenever I try to load my plugin onto a server for testing it throws me the error: Cannot find main class 'me.light.bukkit.Main'

My code for main class:

```
package me.light.bukkit;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    //when plugin is enabled
    public void onEnable() {
        new PlayerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    //when plugin is disabled (ie saving stuff)
    public void onDisable() {

    }
}
```

My code for PlayerListener Class :

```
package me.light.bukkit;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEggThrowEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

public class PlayerListener implements Listener{

    public PlayerListener(Main plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, (Plugin) plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void blank(PlayerEggThrowEvent event) {

        Player player = event.getPlayer();

        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "DO NOT THROW EGGS");

        player.kickPlayer("You were throwing eggs!");

    }
}
```

And finally my plugin.yml

```
name: Illumination
main: me.light.bukkit.Main
version: 1.0
author: kb
description: First Plugin
commands:
```

Also here is the error that the server gave me

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option     MaxPermSize=128M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Loading libraries, please wait...
[19:41:24 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.8
[19:41:24 INFO]: Loading properties
[19:41:25 INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[19:41:25 INFO]: Generating keypair
[19:41:25 INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[19:41:25 INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-    ee6d0fa (
MC: 1.8) (Implementing API version 1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[19:41:25 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\illumination.jar' in folder     'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class     `me.light.bukki
t.Main'
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>    (PluginClassLoader.jav
a:42) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.j
ava:129) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.
java:328) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager
.java:251) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.ja
va:288) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.<init>    (CraftServer.java:25
0) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerList.<init>    (PlayerList.java:69) [c
raftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>    (SourceFile:14
) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.jav
a:133) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
:484) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.light.bukkit.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     ~[?:1.8.0_
25]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.
java:77) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.
java:62) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>    (PluginClassLoader.jav
a:40) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-ee6d0fa]
        ... 10 more
[19:41:25 INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[19:41:25 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed:     -6785130429683314732)

[19:41:26 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed:     -6785130429683314732)

[19:41:26 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed:     -6785130429683314732)

[19:41:26 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty,     ignoring it
[19:41:26 INFO]: Done (1.351s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

I have tried to fix this numerous times but to no avail. I have tried renaming things in my plugin.yml, moving my plugin.yml around in my plugin, and changing the names of my classes but nothing has worked. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see nothing wrong... Is your plugin in the `src` folder, and not in a `package`? If it's in the `src`, try deleting and re-creating the plugin.yml with nothing but the `main`, `version`, and `name` parameters.

Comment: Have you try posting your question in [Bukkit](http://dev.bukkit.org)?

Comment: Figured it out. Sorry guys I had been exporting it wrong.

Comment: @user3499995 How so? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @user3499995 i'm having the same problem and already tried everything, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all... this is a weird plugin.
Second I'm not sure that doing this is good(Im really not sur so don't blame):

```
public PlayerListener(Main plugin) {
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, (Plugin) plugin);
}
```

Normally you should do:

```
public void onEnable() {
    bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerListener(), this);
}
```

and delete the:

```
new PlayerListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: you should refactor your plugin and rename *Main* to something else. (e.g. name of the plugin)

```
package me.light.bukkit;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    private PlayerListener playerListener;

    @Override
    //when plugin is enabled
    public void onEnable() {
        playerListener = new PlayerListener(this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(playerListener, this);
    }

    @Override
    //when plugin is disabled (ie saving stuff)
    public void onDisable() {}
}
```

**Listener**

```
package me.light.bukkit;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEggThrowEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

public class PlayerListener implements Listener{
    private Main plugin;

    public PlayerListener(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void blank(PlayerEggThrowEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "DO NOT THROW EGGS");
        player.kickPlayer("You were throwing eggs!");
    }
}
```